# More efficient way to build/transfer a large data structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a mobile Boggle-type web app with node.js. I'm trying find a more efficient way to load/build a massive dictionary (180,000+ words). I currently have it working but the load time is slightly long. Users have to wait about 15 seconds for the entire thing to build and some users time-out before the entire thing has loaded. I was wondering if anyone has any tips to improve the speed.

The way I'm currently doing this (which is probably completely inefficient):

- I broke down the list into 26 arrays, one for each letter, and stuck each array in it's own javascript file.
- When the app loads it runs a recursive function which gets the next js file and loads in the array from it overwriting the previous one. And then, it loops through the entire array and loads each new word into my [Trie](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/&ei=vtwCUcSTCqWz0QHGk4C4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFejE75227FcBY3dNlyz4gL6XCsAQ&bvm=bv.41524429,d.dmQ) datastructure.
- The files with the arrays in them combined are around 2mb. After being combined the datastructure itself clocks in at round 12mb, which isn't so bad on a desktop computer, but does weigh down a couple of my users' smartphones.

This needs to be built on the client side to allow instant lookups. The way I'm doing it currently works but I know there has to be a better way.

Comment: Why not load it as one big gzip'ed file?  Pre-compute the data structure and dump it out as a JSON object.

Comment: Also in my experience trying to get a Trie working so that it's faster than the native JavaScript property name hashing is somewhere between extremely hard and impossible. Seems like a simple object with a whole lot of properties is likely to be the faster; how fast do lookups have to be anyway?

Comment: @Pointy I actually already pre-computed and stored the structure as a JSON object in a .js file. My only problem is the implementation on gzip with node. Seems like a pain.

Comment: You can pre-gzip the .js file and serve it via Apache or nginx or something; serving it with Node should be pretty easy as all you have to do is make sure the header is correct.

Comment: Do you really need to build a 180k words dictionary each time user connects?

Comment: nope not at all. I think I'm gonna take advice from @Pointy and gzip it. Since the dictionary is static I'll just cache it.

Answer (score 0):

The other other tactic is to convert your recursive code into non-recursive code that uses an explicit stack, saving only the objects you actually need.

Have you tried profiling your code?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of the fastest loading time, are you doing it in this fashion? (aka, without more code, we can't possibly know)

```
function LoadFiles(fileArray){
  file = fileArray.slice(); //get the first file.
  $.ajax(file).success(function(data){
    /* yes, my object is a little funky, I'm focused on writing pseudocode */
    wordLibraryAdd(data);

    if (fileArray.length) // on a zero length quit processing
    setTimeout(function(){ LoadFiles(fileArray) }, 50) //a 50 ms buffer between each loading isn't bad.
  })
}
```

Comment: ya i'm doing almost exactly the minus the Timeout function

Comment: The `setTimeout` let's the browser "breathe" so to speak, so try adding that and see if it makes things _seem_ faster.

Comment: You might also try caching into `localStorage` if you can.